# How to exit a shell program

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, system-calls

I'm making simple shell program and trying to exit it if the user enters "exit" and I've tried a few different keywords such as exit(), return 0, break;

This is my code:

```
void read_command(char path[], char *args[], char input[]) {
  char *array[MAX], *ptr;

  char *inputptr;
  if ((inputptr = strchr(input, '\n')) != NULL) {
      *inputptr = '\0';
  }

  int i = 0;
  char *p = strtok(input, " ");
  while (p != NULL) {
      array[i++] = p;
      p = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      args[j] = array[j];
  }
}

int main() {
  char path[MAX];
  char *args[MAX] = {NULL};
  int status;
  char input[MAX];

  while (TRUE) {
      printf(">> ");
      fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

      if (fork() != 0) {
          if (waitpid(-1, &status, 0) < 0) {
              perror("waitpid error ");
          }

      } else {
          read_command(path, args, input);

          if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) {
              exit(0);
          }

          strcpy(path, "/bin/");
          strcat(path, args[0]);

          if (execve(path, args, 0) < 0) {
              perror("exec error ");
              return EXIT_FAILURE;
          }
      }
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I return the strcomp() value it does give me 0 so I'm not sure why it's not working the program seems to completely ignore that exit statement and just carries on with the code, can someone explain how I could to this? Thank you.

Comment: Remember than when you fork, you have two processes come out the other side. They both need to exit.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `exit` in the child process that you just forked off. Instead, read the command in the parent process and then either exit *or* fork. By the way, you should really be checking that fork does not return `-1`:

```
  read_command(path, args, input);

  if (strcmp(input, "exit") == 0)
      /* Don't pass zero here, that's not portable. */
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  pid_t child;
  switch ((child = fork())) {
      case -1:
         perror("fork failed");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      case 0:
         // call exec
      default:
          /* Don't pass -1 here if you know which child to wait for.
             Also, you can just pass NULL if to status */
          if (waitpid(child, NULL, 0) < 0)
              perror("waitpid error ");
  }
```